# What type of In-App Purchase choose for removing ads for one of iOS game app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have implemented ads in one of my game apps and its free but I want to make a in-app purchase feature to remove ads

now i don't have any idea about which type of IAPs option to choose (Consumable, Non-Consumable, Automatically Renewable Subscriptions, Free Subscription, Non-Renewing Subscription). also how much do i need to charge for that.

So can someone helps what kind of in-app purchase is suitable for above and also according to Apple Rules regarding in-app purchase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a **non-consumable** in-app purchase. This means that the user only has to purchase it once, and they then own it forever (regardless of deleting & re-installing the app).

However, it doesn't seem like your that familiar with the workings of in-app purchases, [so I suggest you have a good read of the Apple docs on it.](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf)

When it comes to pricing, that's entirely up to you.